# What is today's equivalent of the ABX.HE index from the mid 2000s that tracked subprime mortgage market?

Tags: securities

Does anyone know what the current day index is and where I can find it?

Comment: According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/abx-index.asp) it still exists... it is "_calculated daily and provided to Index subscribers_". So I don't think you get to find the value unless you pay [IHS Markit](https://ihsmarkit.com/products/markit-abx.html) who created it.

Comment: It seems like this should be a matter of public record.

Comment: Why do you feel that it should? As far as I can see (but I could be wrong), Markit is essentially collating and selling information (about the performance of the RMBS market) that is of potential use/value to (large-scale) investors... why would they give that away? I also came across [Pricing ABX index for Newbies](https://quantnet.com/threads/pricing-abx-index-for-newbies.9949/) on Quantnet which might be useful.